# detect power interruption in Symbian OS

Tags: symbian

Help , How can you detect whenever the power cord is unplugged from electrical socket through Symbian OS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duplicating the Symbian part of the answer from your jsr-256 question:

The Symbian OS C++ API to check battery status is:

CTelephony::TBatteryInfo

Look it up in the Developer Library documentation at:

http://developer.symbian.org/main/documentation/carbide/index.php

Answer (score 4):

The `CTelephony` API has a `GetIndicator()` method, which gives you flags including  `KIndChargerConnected`. There's one set to tell you whether detecting charger connection is supported, and then if it is you check the other to tell you whether a charger is connected. Like HAL, you never know exactly what's supported. I've never used it so I can't give you examples of handsets which do or don't implement it.

You can register for notification of changes with the `NotifyChange()` method, using `EIndicatorChange`.